# Use jQuery to Adjust Ul width based on Li width

Tags: jquery

I have a `ul` whose child `li`s are loaded dynamically based on certain filters. Sometimes it has four list items, sometimes it has thirty.

Each `li` has a fixed width of 250px and a height of 180px. What I need is a jQuery solution to adjust the width of the `ul` based on how many `li` children it contains.

As requested a few lines of code are here:

```
<ul class="ul-list-events-albums">

    <li>
      some text or image here
    </li>
    <li>
      some text or image here
    </li>
    <li>
      some text or image here
    </li>
    <li>
      some text or image here
    </li>
```

```
<style>
ul.ul-list-events-albums{
margin: 0 auto;
width: auto;
               }
ul.ul-list-events-albums li{
margin:10px 0;
margin-right:10px;
    list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;
    width:250px;
    height:180px;
}
```

Why i need jquery to check the total width of list items loaded is cause i'm putting the Ul inside a div with overflow-x:auto;

Comment: You already know the width is fixed

Comment: You need to showus some code

Comment: @CognitiveDesire that's list item width which is fixed as 250px. However list items vary as per the query. I can't use width:100%;

Answer (score 0):

Get the number of children:

```
var count = $("ul li").length;
```

then set the width accordingly:

```
$("ul").width(count * 25);
```